# remover classe depois da 1 com Jquery

Tags: jquery

tenho a seguinte situação onde quero adicionar um classe e remover o resto de pois da 1

```html
<div class="voted rating-box color ">

</div>
```

esse e o html onde a div tem 3 classe ao executar a função quero remover todas as classes mais deixando a 1 e adicionando a classe star ficaria assim

```html
<div class="voted star ">

</div>
```

```
$(".voted").removeClass().addClass('star');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você estava quase conseguindo apenas faltou adicionar novamente a classe **voted** que havia removido:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.voted').removeClass().addClass('voted star');
  console.log($('div').prop('class'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="voted rating-box color">teste</div>
```

Comment: obrigado deu certo era tão facil .